# How do I get my Arduino Yún to receive push notifications with Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, arduino-yun

I followed the [Quick Start Guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/arduinoyun) to set up receiving Parse Push notifications on my Arduino Yún.

I'm using the Yún embedded SDK 1.0.3-1.

It only works once, on reboot or whenever .setup() is called.

Afterwards, receiving pushes does not work, regardless of whether I'm sending from either the dashboard or a javascript client.

Comment: It may be helpful if you posted some code so that we can take a look

Comment: @JohnDavis I copied and pasted the code from the [Quick Start Guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/arduinoyun)

Comment: Still though, it is hard to troubleshoot without context. Even if it is copy/paste, if you posted the entire sketch here, it would at least give us a starting point.